# How do I fetch information from a api with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to fetch ethereums price from this url:

`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum`/

How would I get that information, and have it automatically update it whenever it changes?

Comment: Need more info about your variables.  How are you defining `session`?

Comment: Ill add the full code?

Comment: Added all of the code @dbJones

Comment: Why are you trying to pass `session` as an argument?  The arguments that are passed into a command are parsed from the command given in discord.  THere's no way for a user to transmit a `session` to you.  You should really use `aiohttp` with `discord.py` anyways.  If your web request takes too long the event loop will likely just kill your bot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import aiohttp

@client.command()
async def eth(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            value = await resp.json()['price_usd']
            await client.say("Ethereum price is: ${}".format(value))
```

It seems like you have an endpoint in mind for this request.  It probably makes more sense to hardcode that endpoint and don't have the user enter anything at all (remove the `url` argument entirely and have a `url = 'https://...'` line in the coroutine body)

Edit: as above, so below

```
import aiohttp

@client.command()
async def eth():
    url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            value = await resp.json()['price_usd']
            await client.say("Ethereum price is: ${}".format(value))
```

Comment: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/ the url is this, where would it go specifically?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call las):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Im not sure what that is about out... you have any idea?

Comment: Oops, `resp.json` is a coroutine, so you have to use `await`.

Comment: I get the error:

    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any idea what thats about?